# Why is Visual Studio 2017 allowing GIT pull with uncommitted changes?

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I could be remembering this incorrectly, but it seems to me like Visual Studio never allowed me to pull while I had any uncommitted changes.

However, suddenly, we're able to do just that.
This is problematic because it makes room for so many mistakes.

Did I accidentally modify a setting somewhere?

Using TFS, GIT, VS 2017

Comment: I think current versions of Git would allow a pull if the changes would not be in conflict with whatever new information is coming in.  Best practice is to just not pull if you know your working directory or stage is not clean.

Comment: Problem is, people make mistakes.  I'll check out the conflict idea, but I was pretty sure that a month ago, any uncommitted changes (conflicting or not) prevented attempting a pull

Comment: For reasons like this, I never use Git plugins in the IDE (such as eGit), but rather I always use the command line, at least for basic workflow stuff.

Comment: Update: well you were right about the conflict (at least on my machine).  I had our jr. dev make a conflicting change and commit/push, while I made a change on the same file and didn't commit.  When I attempted a pull, I got the "uncommitted changes" message as expected.  However, what made me look into this at all, was that he had been able to pull a file with a conflict while having uncommitted changes.  The result was that the change I pushed was in history, but the file in his repo reflected his changes on top of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [git pull documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull):

> In Git 1.7.0 or later, to cancel a conflicting merge, use git reset
>   --merge. Warning: In older versions of Git, running git pull with uncommitted changes is discouraged: while possible, it leaves you in a
>   state that may be hard to back out of in the case of a conflict.
>
> If any of the remote changes overlap with local uncommitted changes,
>   the merge will be automatically canceled and the work tree untouched.
>   It is generally best to get any local changes in working order before
>   pulling or stash them away with [git-stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).

The second paragraph describes the behavior you're observing.

Comment: I'm just taken aback as to how my jr was able to pull my commit down while he had conflicting local changes that were uncommitted.  The result being my commit in his history, but the file reflecting his changes on top of it.  It's almost like it pulled the commit then applied his uncommitted changes on top of it.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael The behavior you are describing is actually `git pull --rebase`.  Google for that exact phrase.  Then, check your actual settings.